# typescript: array.filter(isObject)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do conditional mongodb aggregations:

```
collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {}},
  flag & {$lookup: {}},
  flag & {$match: {}},
].filter(isObject))
```

For that to work I need a typesafe isObject function that works with array.filter.

```
function isString<T>(argument: T | string): argument is string {
  return typeof argument === 'string';
}

function isObject<T>(argument: T | object): argument is object {
    return argument !== null && typeof argument === 'object'
}

// works
const stringArray: string[] = [
    '{match: 1}',
    false,
    null
].filter(isString)

// doesn't work
const objectArray: object[] = [
    {match: 1},
    false,
    null
].filter(isObject)
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgZSgJxmA5gHgBUA+ACgENNcQBbAUzCgC5FDEAfRFLHXAShaVq9RshRceeRAG8AsAChEiTHSghMSKAE8ADnTjBEQ2gyiIAvJcQBybtjzWA3AoC+ChaEiwEYgPIAjACs6aCIyYxFmVg5EOCCQqAEjKhNRVFj46BkFJSUVNQ1k4VNEAEIrMBAAGyrEADI6xG09AyLUs0tzGzjg6GtXd3kAeiHEAHc4TABrFAUIBG4Je1wAQUxMci0WO14AbQBdC0RdnNzraRpyKAgACxYARhdrABpTpWByKpQ6V8VcypqCn2ADpgDAqlA6JhSKgMMs+IMRogACZwOgoMDWMwTaZzBZmHoJNYbLYZXpQA5HE5-JQXK63B4uX65RAfL4-N6IAFVIGg8GQ6GoALkvhAA)

For some reason if I provide real objects it doesn't work. But, it starts to work if I do:

```
// works again
const objectArray: object[] = [
    {match: 1} as object,
    false,
    null
].filter(isObject)
```

I don't want to do that and also I don't want to do "array.reduce" or "array.flatMap" or my colleagues beat me up for a bad codestyle.

Is there any way to do that nice and clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work

```
function isObject<T>(argument: T): argument is Exclude<T, null> & object  {
    return argument !== null && typeof argument === 'object';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 

`function isObject<T>(argument: T): argument is T & object` works too. 

That doesn't make sense to me, but works.